# Accordion tabs not opening by default on configurable product

Tags: product-view, accordion

I changed product details from tab to accordion. I want all of the tabs to be open by default. This works on simple products, but doesn't work on configurable products.

I've been editing the details.phtml file. Is there a different file for configurable products?

Here's the code and some screenshots

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'accordion'], function ($) {
        $(".product.data.items").accordion({
            "openedState":"active",
            "collapsible": true,
            "active": [0,1,2,3,4],
            "multipleCollapsible": true
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: Simple Product]

[image: Configurable Product]

Comment: Have you check console or Magento log file for the error?

Comment: No errors related to this at all